# How to open modal using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image and when i click the image i want to open the image in a modal but when i click the the image, modal is not working or not showing. Is there anyone here that can help?

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-thumbnail" >
         <a id="myModal" href="#" title="Cappuccino"><img id="cap_mod" class="img-responsive"  src="images/Portfolio-img/flyer/thumb/cappuccino-thumb.jpg" alt="cappuccino"></a>
      </div>
</div><!--END OF col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->


<!--MODAL CAPPUCCINO IMAGE GALLERY-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myMODAL1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

              <button type="button" class="close" data dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

           <h4 class="modal-title">BROCHURE - Cappuccino</h4>
         </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <img id="cappuccino_mod" class="img-responsive"  
        src="images/Portfolio-img/flyer/image-modal/cappuccino-
        modal.jpg" alt="cappuccino">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
        dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <div>
    </div><!--END OF MODAL MODAL CAPPUCCINO IMAGE GALLERY-->  



<script>
    $(document).ready(function){
    $("#myModal").on('click',(function){
        $("#cap_mod").attr('src',$("#cappuccino_mod").attr('src'));
        $("#myMODAL1").modal('show');})
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax mistakes in your code I have modified it have a look below :-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#myModal").on('click',function() {
               $("#cap_mod").attr('src',$("#cappuccino_mod").attr('src'));
               $("#myMODAL1").show('slow');
        });        
    });
```

Demo :-
http://jsfiddle.net/yruopsg9/5/

I hope this is what you want!

Comment: it's not the alert that i want, when i click a thumbnail i want to show the image inside of a modal.

Comment: I have removed alert it was just for testing @egtdesign

Comment: thanks. neel, i have two modals in my body page one for contact and one for this image. the code you just edited still not working for me although it's working in the fiddle, is it because i have two modals that's why it's not working?

Comment: well if you have 2 modals then you have to give different ids to each modal or give comman class name to both of them @egtdesign it would be better if you post your whole not working code in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap code needs to be fixed. No need for any javascript except for bootstrap.js and jQuery included on the page

here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/4pzuydjm/)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">

<a href="#" title="Cappuccino" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<img id="cap_mod" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="cappuccino"/></a>

</div><!--END OF col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->

<!--MODAL CAPPUCCINO IMAGE GALLERY-->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;    </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">BROCHURE - Cappuccino</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     <img id="cappuccino_mod" class="img-responsive"  
    src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="cappuccino"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```